# VB.NET Connected SAP WSDL Preventing Solution from building

Tags: vb.net, wsdl

I'm trying to build a .NET Class Library that utilises a SAP generated WSDL.

In the `reference.vb` file that one of the WSDLs generates, I'm getting the following error in this line:

```
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form:=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order:=0)>  _
```

With the error being `BC30369   Cannot refer to an instance member of a class from within a shared method or shared member initializer without an explicit instance of the class.` on `System`.

This only occurs within one of the generated Partial Public Classes that it generates, and not the rest.

Comment: Could you show the code around that line? Seems strange that a decorator could throw such an error.

Answer (score 0):

After removing System it works:

'''
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form:=Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)>
Public Property MESSAGE_V4() As String
Get
Return Me.mESSAGE_V4Field
End Get
Set
Me.mESSAGE_V4Field = Value
End Set
End Property

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).